# Xml to column based data using SQL + XQuery

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have the following xml in my xml-typed column (xml itself is un-typed)

```
<wi>
  <w wid="16">
    <p>28</p>
    <p>72</p>
    <p>125</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="19">
    <p>89</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="20">
    <p>11</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="21">
    <p>74</p>
  </w>
</wi>
```

Can't figure out how to produce two-columns using SQL+XQuery:

```
 p    w
---  ---
11   20
28   16
72   16
74   21
89   19
125  16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
declare @x xml = '<wi>
  <w wid="16">
    <p>28</p>
    <p>72</p>
    <p>125</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="19">
    <p>89</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="20">
    <p>11</p>
  </w>
  <w wid="21">
    <p>74</p>
  </w>
</wi>'

select *
from
(
    select t.c.value('.', 'int') p
        , t.c.value('../@wid', 'int') w
    from @x.nodes('//p') t(c)
)t
order by p, w
```

Comment: Assuming I added namespace to the root node: <wi xmlns="http://example.com">, how do I specify it in the value() call? no syntax I try works.

Comment: I guess a better question would be - assuming I have a schema, how do I specify that schema in the value() call? I already added 

"with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://example.com')" to the sql query

Answer (score 2):

Or another approach using `cross apply`:

```
select *
from
(
    select a.b.value('.', 'int') p
        , t.c.value('@wid', 'int') w
    from @x.nodes('//w') t(c)
    cross apply t.c.nodes('p') a(b)
)t
order by p, w
```

Comment: You will have better performance not using the parent axis `..`. +1 for this version.